# NSMutableArray causing crash

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

I am sorry for the long post but I am at my wits end and have been stumped for days over this. Here's the scenario. My app loads a response from core data, converts the values to NSStrings so that I can add them to an NSDictionary. Then the NSDictionary is converted to NSData so I can attach it as a file to email. The purpose of this is so I can create a database of information including images, videos, etc. I was able to get everything to work except I am having an issue with an NSMutableArray. Here's the process:

I create an event and then load the data for exporting with this code.

```
EventDB *per = [[EventDB alloc]init];
per.customLayoutArray = [record.customLayoutArray description] ?
[record.customLayoutArray description] : @"";
NSDictionary *dict = [per dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"customLayoutArray"];
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
```

Then I email the data using MFMailComposer. Then I have a custom UTI that allows me the open the url from the email and then I import the data and load it into my coredata entity with this

```
if([[url pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"ipix"]) {
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TSPItem" 
   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    TSPItem *record = (TSPItem *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity
   insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    if (record) {

   NSString *datetime = [jsonData objectForKey:@"customLayoutArray"];
        record.customLayoutArray = [[datetime propertyList] mutableCopy];
     }
```

That works fine. It does import the way I want but when I launch the event I get this crash message

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[__NSCFString apply]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c81a5f60
```

Now here's the code where it crashes.

```
 NSMutableArray *archiveArray = self.record.customLayoutArray;
NSString *mycustom = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_customlayout", 
                                            self.record.eventname];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:archiveArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:mycustom];
self.customLayoutArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];


NSLog(@"BOOTH EVENT ID %@", self.customLayoutArray);
[self.customLayoutArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(apply)];
```

This is the log from BOOTH EVENT ID

```
 BOOTH EVENT ID (
"<Rectangle:0x102d38cb0self.scaleValue=1.842393\n, self.rotateValue=0.000000\n, self.width=368.478516\n, self.height=368.478516\n, self.radius=0\n, self.frame={{104, 113.5}, {200, 200}}\n, self.isApplied=NO\n>",
"<Rectangle:0x102d393c0self.scaleValue=1.000000\n, self.rotateValue=0.000000\n, self.width=200.000000\n, self.height=200.000000\n, self.radius=0\n, self.frame={{253, 273.5}, {200, 200}}\n, self.isApplied=NO\n>"
)
```

The app crashes here. Now if I load the original event on my iPad (the one that I didn't export) the app works perfect and the NSLog response for BOOTH EVENT ID is identical.

The "apply" section refers to this file.

```
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "DeviceSize.h"

@implementation Rectangle

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


}
return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
[coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.scaleValue] forKey:@"ScaleValue"];
[coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.rotateValue] forKey:@"RotateValue"];

[coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.width] forKey:@"Width"];
[coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.height] forKey:@"Height"];

[coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.radius] forKey:@"Radius"];
[coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.isApplied] forKey:@"isApplied"];

[coder encodeObject:self.image forKey:@"Image"];
[coder encodeObject:self.backgroundColor forKey:@"BackgroundColor"];
[coder encodeObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.center]    forKey:@"CenterPoint"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.scaleValue = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"ScaleValue"]  floatValue];
    self.rotateValue = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"RotateValue"] floatValue];

    self.width = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Width"] floatValue];
    self.height = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Height"] floatValue];

    self.radius = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Radius"] integerValue];
    self.isApplied = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"isApplied"] boolValue];

    [self.layer setCornerRadius:self.radius];
    self.image = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Image"];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"BackgroundColor"]];
    //


    if (self.width == self.height)
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0,200, 200);
        self.frame = rect;

    }

    if (self.width > self.height)
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0,200, 150);
        self.frame = rect;

    }

    if (self.width < self.height)
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0,150, 200);
        self.frame = rect;

    }


    self.center = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"CenterPoint"] CGPointValue];


}
return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
/* Set UIView Border */
// Get the contextRef
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set the border width
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 5.0);

// Set the border color to RED
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

// Draw the border along the view edge
CGContextStrokeRect(contextRef, rect);
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
return YES;
}

- (NSString *)description {
NSMutableString *description = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<%@:%p", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self];

[description appendFormat:@"self.scaleValue=%f\n", self.scaleValue];
[description appendFormat:@", self.rotateValue=%f\n", self.rotateValue];
[description appendFormat:@", self.width=%f\n", self.width];
[description appendFormat:@", self.height=%f\n", self.height];
[description appendFormat:@", self.radius=%li\n", (long)self.radius];
[description appendFormat:@", self.frame=%@\n", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame)];
[description appendFormat:@", self.isApplied=%@\n", self.isApplied ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
[description appendString:@">"];
return description;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
Rectangle *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];

if (copy != nil) {
    copy.scaleValue = self.scaleValue;
    copy.rotateValue = self.rotateValue;
    copy.width = self.width;
    copy.height = self.height;
    copy.radius = self.radius;
    copy.frame = self.frame;
    copy.isApplied = self.isApplied;
}

return copy;
}


@end


@implementation Rectangle(ApplyRotate)

#pragma mark -
- (Rectangle *)apply {
if (self.isApplied) {
    return self;
}

Rectangle *rectangle = self;
CGPoint centerPoint = rectangle.center;

CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(rectangle.rotateValue));
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(rectangle.scaleValue, rectangle.scaleValue);
CGAffineTransform scaleAndRotate = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotate, scale);
rectangle.transform = scaleAndRotate;

rectangle.center = centerPoint;
rectangle.isApplied = YES;

return rectangle;
}

@end
```

Comment: The error is saying that `apply` doesn't work on strings, which is reasonable.  This: `[record.customLayoutArray description]` results in a string, which you then save.  In other words, you've set up encoding for your object but I don't see that you're using it.

Comment: So I am still having issues with crashing. record.customLayoutArray is an NSMutableArray so I thought this line would save the NSString response to NSMutableArray ** (record.customLayoutArray = [[datetime propertyList] mutableCopy] )** It's not working. Basically I need to extract the values from the String and then add them into a new NSMutableArray. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Are you having the same problem or a new one?  (If new, try asking a new question with relevant details.)